# Must you have a release certificate before generating a Google Maps key?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am reading the following documentation to get a Google Maps API key for Google Maps V2:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

It says you must locate your release certificate keystore file and run the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

And then copy the SHA1 line of the certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint to the Google API Console.

But wait a second. When you generate the keystore, it means you are ready to publish the app. But if you have to generate the Google Maps Key AFTER you generate the keystore, doesn't that mean you have to generate the keystore again to reflect the changes made to the AndroidManifest.xml where you added the Google Maps key?

Comment: This means, You'll make a keystore, generate the key through it. Eventually you'll use that keystore to sign your app when releasing. Generating a keystore is required once in an app's life, not every time you change the manifest.  By default every app you compile is signed with a debug keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore contains a certificate. A certificate confirms the identity of the person who signs the app and it can never be changed once you upload your app. Different certificate means different person even if the metadata (e.g. name, organization etc) are the same.

> doesn't that mean you have to generate the keystore again to reflect the changes made to the AndroidManifest.xml where you added the Google Maps key?

The answer is no. You don't have to generate new keystore (doing so you will not be able to update your published app). You just have to resign your updated apk with your existing certificate.

Comment: And how do you resign your updated application? I made a change to the application. Now I go to Build > Generate Signed APK and then I follow the steps. It says it successfully generated the APK but when I look at the file, it shows the modified stamp was never changed.

Comment: Ok I see now. It modifies the APK file, not the keystore file. And the APK file is located in the project, whereas the keystore is located at ~/.android.